# skype for business automation to outlook

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have to add a feature in Skype for Business to open automatically a new Outlook task window when a call starts, with the phone number of the called/calling contact in the subject field. Is there any addin or api in order to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **Lync SDK 2013**, new conversation added event can be handled where you can also get participant related information. Inside conversation added event handler listen for AVModality state changes. When AVModality state is changed to connected, using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook** outlook application can be automated and new task window can be created as given below

```
LyncClient lyncClient = new LyncClient();
lyncClient.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += OnConversationAdded;

private void OnConversationAdded(object sender, Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManagerEventArgs e)
{
    e.Conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].ModalityStateChanged +=  OnAudioVideoModalityStateChanged;
}

private void OnAudioVideoModalityStateChanged(object sender, ModalityStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.NewState)
    {
        case ModalityState.Connected:
            Application oOutlook = null;
            oOutlook = new Application();
            TaskItem oTask  = (TaskItem)oOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olTaskItem);
            oTask.Subject = "Testing";
            oTask.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            oTask.Display(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

For more information : 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx),
[Lync SDK 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36824)

Comment: Thank you Kannan. Just another question because I'm a beginner :( I can't understand how to create the project. I shall install Lync SDK 2013 which requires Lync 2013. I have SFB. Lync is out of date

Comment: Install lync sdk and add reference to Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll in your project. If you are getting installation error "lync 2013 not found", try this solution: https://elbruno.com/2016/05/25/windows10-installing-lync-2013-sdk-to-use-it-on-skype-for-business-2016-welcometohell/